# How to push an existing project to a new sub-folder in Github repository using gitbash?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

So I understand I cannot create an empty subfolder in Github. I have a few different project I've done and I want to push these project into different subfolders in my Projects repository, such as:

```
myId / Projects / project_1 / project_1.py
. . . . . . . . / project_2 / project_2.py
```

I know how to push an existing project to my Projects repository, using:

```
git init
git add project_1.py
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin <URL>
git push origin master
```

But I want to push an existing project to a new subfolder to Projects repository. 
How can I do this? So far, I've only tried to just create a subfolder in Github repository, creating one text file then upload *project_1.py* manually, then delete the text file. But I wanted to know if I can do this using Gitbash...

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: @matt oh so sorry I actually thought you gave up on my question as my question sounded stupid and not-understandable (I was gonna re-write the whole question), and that your answer didn't work, (which I assumed I did something stupid again) and I didn't know how to reply to you and I got frustrated. So I just deleted it. Sorry, I genuinely thought my post was done. :-(

Comment: @matt I really appreciate your help even after I deleted the post. Now I understand why it didn't work as I expected. I didn't know ```git mv``` just changes the name.

Comment: Well, your question now still isn't very clear. You can't push "a project to a subfolder". You have _one_ project folder on your computer and _one_ project repository on github. If you make a folder inside your project folder on your computer and put a file inside it, you will get the same folder and file on github. It's simple. It works just like you would expect.

Comment: Ahhh Thank you so much, I think I fix the problem. I think I was in the wrong directory on my computer, so when I pushed the project, somehow I got 2 folders and no python files in the repository. Thanks!!!